# Telegram Bot API - Using "getFile" with a high-quality photo's "file_id" yields a link to low-quality file

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm well aware this question seems like a possible duplicate (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106191/how-to-get-photo-in-real-size-not-thumb-from-telegram), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052361/how-to-download-full-size-photo-using-telegram-bot-api-uploaded-from-user), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082572/telegram-bot-download-image-file)), but I couldn't find a straight answer to my scenario anywhere.
The exact flow is as follows:

1. The Bot receives a message with a photo from a user. It then extracts and stores the `file_id` of the highest-quality photo out of the `message.photo` array (the last array item).
2. The bot fires a `getFile(file_id)` request using the stored `file_id`, which returns a **single** link (**NOT an array**) that points to a **low-quality** file (slightly bigger than a thumbnail).

To summarize:

- Using the exact `file_id` with `getFile()` returns a link to a low-quality file.
- Using the exact `file_id` with `sendPhoto()` will send a full-size photo.

On the chance I'm missing something here, can anyone confirm that that's expected behavior? Thanks.

Comment: I admit I've the same question. In fact, if you dump the reply from Telegram you'll see that you get an array with all info about all the images sizes, all with different "file_unique_id" but all the "file_id" that we send to telegram to get the path are... the same. Need more investigation...

Answer (score 4):

file_id's are different in the photo array. use file_id which has the biggest file_size and then you could get the high quality file by getFile method

Comment: Thanks, @konstantin, The issue I experienced was that getFile(file_id) returned a link that pointed to a low-quality photo even though the file_id I supplied represented an HQ photo

Answer (score 0):

Base on image resolution, "photo" array contains different number file_id. Use `ctx.message.photo.lenght - 1` to access the last file_id for best quality.

Answer (score 0):

the best quality in -1 index

```
    raw = message.photo[-1].file_id
    
    path =path+"/"+raw+".jpg"

    file_info = bot.get_file(raw)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    with open(path,'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ali, this part is clear to me though. The issue I experienced was that `getFile(file_id)` returned a link that pointed to a low-quality photo, even though the `file_id` I supplied represented an HQ photo.

Comment: Hi dear, `raw = message.photo[-1].file_id ` in this line if you choose -1 index, you will get the best quality of image or file.

Comment: Again, this part is clear to me. My question is different.. nevermind :)